# File upload permission problem IIS 7

Tags: file, iis-7, upload

I am unable to upload files to website hosted under IIS7. I have already given write permissions to "IUSR_websitename" and set the property  in web.config also.

I am able to upload files with out log in to application at the time of user registration. But once log in to application, if I upload files, it is giving "Access denied" error.

Please help me.

Comment: You should post this on Server Fault. This is not a programming related question.

Answer (score 0):

Is your web site set up to do impersonation?  If so, it's using the user's credentials not those of the worker process after you authenticate.

Comment: I have just set the <identity impersonate="true" /> in web.config.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting that you do that.  I just wondered if you were doing that, which would cause your problem since after authentication the process would no longer have rights to write to the upload directory.